# Solar Impulse lift to drag ratio

Tags: glide-ratio, solar-impulse

What are the L/D ratios of the two Solar Impulse airplanes? I haven't been able to find them.

Answer (score 2):

[Solar Impulse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Impulse)1 had 4 × 7.5 kW (10 hp) electric motors and a MTOW of around 4400 pounds, and was able to cruise at 43 mph, with 11 foot propellers.

Solar Impulse 2 had 4 × 13 kW (17.4 hp) each at 5100 lbs, and was able to cruise at 56 mph, with 13 foot propellers.

According to [this](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/air-space-magazine/seven-thousand-kilometers-no-gas-180956016) article, the lift to drag ratio was around 37:1.

Rough calculation of 4 × 17.5 hp cruising at half throttle generating 4 pounds of thrust per hp

> 5100 lbs/(4×17.5 hp×4 lbs/hp×0.5) = 36.4

This is quite good for powered aircraft$^1$.  Airliners range in the high teens, with the [U-2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2) at 25.6.

$^1$  unless they can retract their power unit into the fuselage